# Convert negative java long to clickhouse Uint64 in prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc, clickhouse

Is there any way to convert negative long to Uint64 (clickhouse data type) before inserting. For now

```
preparedStatement.setObject(columnNumber, -3108819769473315784);
preparedStatement.execute();
```

throws following exception

```
ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseException: ClickHouse exception, code: 321, host:
localhost, port: 33493; Code: 321, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Expression returns value
NULL, that is out of range of type UInt64, at: -3108819769473315784
```

I understand why clickhouse complains. Can you suggest me any solution how to overcome this issue? May be any way to convert this negative long to other type of object?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be `Long`? What if you used `BigInteger` instead?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Java 8 you can use [`Long.toUnsignedString(values)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#toUnsignedString(long)):

```
preparedStatement.setObject(columnNumber, Long.toUnsignedString( -3108819769473315784));
```

Comment: new BigInteger(Long.toUnsignedString( -3108819769473315784)) helped. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the values before they're sent to ClickHouse.
That said, when inserting a negative value to column of `UInt` type, you need to convert it manually to positive value / whatever you want it to be represented as in ClickHouse in range of that target type.

Same applies for eg. handling `null`s when sending to non-nullable column types.